# How to connect Presto to Mongodb container

Tags: sql, mongodb, containers, presto

**Problem: Can't connect presto container to mongodb container.**

I have three running containers:

```
    [root@localhost tmp]# docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
8f6686547c55        mongo               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   tmp_mongo_1
0b639ef12c12        mongo-express       "tini -- /docker-ent…"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp     tmp_mongo-express_1
c51178e29a3e        prestosql/presto    "/usr/lib/presto/bin…"   4 days ago          Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp     presto
```

presto container can access mongo db (network-wise):

```
[root@c51178e29a3e /]# ping mongo
PING mongo (172.20.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from tmp_mongo_1.tmp_default (172.20.0.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.130 ms
64 bytes from tmp_mongo_1.tmp_default (172.20.0.3): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.108 ms
```

Presto properties configured as well (/usr/lib/presto/default/etc/catalog/mongodb.properties):

```
connector.name=mongodb
mongodb.seeds=mongo:27017
mongodb.credentials=root:example@liran
```

The "liran" collection exist:
[image]

When trying to access mongo's "liran" collection:

```
    presto> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mongodb.local.liran;
Query 20191216_154753_00000_sz73z failed: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=mongo:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='root', source='liran', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}}, caused by {com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18: 'Authentication failed.' on server mongo:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Authentication failed.", "code" : 18, "codeName" : "AuthenticationFailed" }}}]
```

while on mongo I get:

```
    mongo_1          | 2019-12-16T15:51:00.795+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn322] end connection 172.20.0.4:34810 (4 connections now open)
mongo_1          | 2019-12-16T15:51:10.796+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.20.0.4:34812 #323 (5 connections now open)
mongo_1          | 2019-12-16T15:51:10.796+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn323] received client metadata from 172.20.0.4:34812 conn323: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver", version: "3.6.0" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/11.0.4+11-LTS" }
mongo_1          | 2019-12-16T15:51:10.798+0000 I  ACCESS   [conn323] SASL SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for root on liran from client 172.20.0.4:34812 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user "root" for db "liran"
mongo_1          | 2019-12-16T15:51:10.799+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn323] end connection 172.20.0.4:34812 (4 connections now open)
mongo_1          | 2019-12-16T15:51:20.800+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.20.0.4:34818 #324 (5 connections now open)
mongo_1          | 2019-12-16T15:51:20.801+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn324] received client metadata from 172.20.0.4:34818 conn324: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver", version: "3.6.0" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/11.0.4+11-LTS" }
mongo_1          | 2019-12-16T15:51:20.803+0000 I  ACCESS   [conn324] SASL SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for root on liran from client 172.20.0.4:34818 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user "root" for db "liran"
mongo_1          | 2019-12-16T15:51:20.804+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn324] end connection 172.20.0.4:34818 (4 connections now open)
mongo_1          | 2019-12-16T15:51:30.806+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.20.0.4:34820 #325 (5 connections now open)
mongo_1          | 2019-12-16T15:51:30.807+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn325] received client metadata from 172.20.0.4:34820 conn325: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver", version: "3.6.0" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/11.0.4+11-LTS" }
mongo_1          | 2019-12-16T15:51:30.809+0000 I  ACCESS   [conn325] SASL SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for root on liran from client 172.20.0.4:34820 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user "root" for db "liran"
mongo_1          | 2019-12-16T15:51:30.810+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn325] end connection 172.20.0.4:34820 (4 connections now open)
mongo_1          | 2019-12-16T15:51:40.811+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.20.0.4:34822 #326 (5 connections now open)
mongo_1          | 2019-12-16T15:51:40.812+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn326] received client metadata from 172.20.0.4:34822 conn326: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver", version: "3.6.0" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", architecture: "amd64", version: "3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/11.0.4+11-LTS" }
mongo_1          | 2019-12-16T15:51:40.814+0000 I  ACCESS   [conn326] SASL SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for root on liran from client 172.20.0.4:34822 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user "root" for db "liran"
```

changing the mongodb.credentials=root:example@local just gives the same error with local instead of liran.

One last thing, when I ran the mongo containers I have used the following stack.yml:

```
    [root@localhost tmp]# cat stack.yml 

# Use root/example as user/password credentials
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      net.tls.mode: disabled

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
```

The dockers being used: 
[mongo](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo), [presto](https://hub.docker.com/r/prestosql/presto)

Answer (score 1):

We need to put the "Authentication database" after @ as below. The default name in the docker image will be "admin".

```
connector.name=mongodb
mongodb.seeds=mongo:27017
mongodb.credentials=root:example@admin
```

Comment: Thanks. Now "liran" collection is under admin db but I get this error:
presto> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mongodb.admin.liran;
Query 20191218_155830_00007_us7wh failed: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=25a1ed6ef906:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake}, caused by {java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly}}]

Comment: same with the mongo instead the container name: 
presto> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mongodb.admin.liran;
Query 20191218_161403_00003_fh2vp failed: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=**mongo***:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake}, caused by {java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly}}]

Comment: Could you confirm the network connection between Presto and MongoDB? Also, I would invite you to join our community Slack (https://prestosql.io/slack.html) so that we can talk interactively.

Comment: Sure. both methods work.
1) [root@c51178e29a3e /]# ping -a mongo
PING mongo (172.21.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from docker_mongo_1.docker_default (172.21.0.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.125 ms
2)[root@c51178e29a3e /]# ping -a 25a1ed6ef906
PING 25a1ed6ef906 (172.21.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from docker_mongo_1.docker_default (172.21.0.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.125 ms

both containers under same docker network ("Name": "docker_default").

it looks more like a TLS problem. I will join Slack.

Answer (score 0):

There were two problems:

1. The mongo container is set with access to admin db while I was
   trying to access local db.
   As depicted in the mongo's docker hub:

   *MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME, MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
   These variables, used in conjunction, create a new user and set that 
    user's password. This user is created in the **admin** authentication 
   database and given the role of root, which is a "superuser" role.*
2. Presto config file
   (/usr/lib/presto/default/etc/catalog/mongodb.properties) was set to
   use TLS while the mongo's container was not.
   changing the property **mongodb.ssl.enabled=false**
   the error in the mongo container gave the clue:

   *mongo_1          | 2019-12-19T12:51:45.607+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn2254] Error receiving request from client: SSLHandshakeFailed: SSL handshake received but **server is started without SSL support**. Ending connection from 172.21.0.4:47702 (connection id: 2254)*

**Finally**:
presto> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mongodb.admin.liran;

### _col0

29353 
(1 row)

Query 20191219_125214_00000_6983x, FINISHED, 1 node
Splits: 18 total, 18 done (100.00%)
0:02 [29.4K rows, 681B] [17.8K rows/s, 411B/s]